# different control flow between running and debugging

Tags: c#, debugging, control-flow

I'm writing a program whose behavior I've designed to be a function of a single text input from the user and nothing else. No use of the system clock, no references to external files, no multi-threading. However, the program is executing with a different control flow when I run it than when I debug it, which I thought should be impossible under those circumstances.

It won't compile on its own, but here is the function that is behaving unexpectedly:

```
static public Dictionary<ComplexNumber, int> getFactorization(ComplexNumber xGaussian)
        {
            Dictionary<ComplexNumber, int> factors = new Dictionary<ComplexNumber, int>();
            int sumOfRealAndImaginary = 2;
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sumOfRealAndImaginary);//test
                int realPart = sumOfRealAndImaginary / 2;
                int imaginaryPart = sumOfRealAndImaginary - realPart;
                for (int i = 0; realPart - i >= 0;) 
                {
                    if ((realPart - i) * (realPart - i) +
                        (imaginaryPart + i) * (imaginaryPart + i) >
                        xGaussian.getRealPart().getNumerator() *
                        xGaussian.getRealPart().getNumerator() +
                        xGaussian.getImaginaryPart().getNumerator() *
                        xGaussian.getImaginaryPart().getNumerator())
                    {
                        if (factors.ContainsKey(xGaussian))
                            factors[xGaussian] += 1;
                        else
                            factors.Add(xGaussian, 1);
                        return factors;
                    }
                    ComplexNumber factor =
                        new ComplexNumber(realPart - i, imaginaryPart + i);
                    ComplexNumber quotient = (ComplexNumber)(xGaussian / factor);
                    quotient.getRealPart().reduce();
                    quotient.getImaginaryPart().reduce();
                    if (quotient.getRealPart().getDenominator() == 1 &&
                        quotient.getImaginaryPart().getDenominator() == 1) 
                    {
                        if (factors.ContainsKey(factor))
                            factors[factor] += 1;
                        else
                            factors.Add(factor, 1);
                        xGaussian = (ComplexNumber)(xGaussian / factor);
                        continue;
                    }
                    factor = new ComplexNumber(realPart - i, -imaginaryPart - i);
                    quotient = (ComplexNumber)(xGaussian / factor);
                    quotient.getRealPart().reduce();
                    quotient.getImaginaryPart().reduce();
                    if (quotient.getRealPart().getDenominator() == 1 &&
                        quotient.getImaginaryPart().getDenominator() == 1)
                    {
                        if (factors.ContainsKey(factor))
                            factors[factor] += 1;
                        else
                            factors.Add(factor, 1);
                        xGaussian = (ComplexNumber)(xGaussian / factor);
                        continue;
                    }
                    ++i;
                }
                ++sumOfRealAndImaginary;
            }
        }
```

The ComplexNumber type is designed to behave the way complex numbers do in math, though limited to real and imaginary parts that are rational, so I'll type the value of a ComplexNumber object the same way as I would a complex number in math. This version of getFactorization() assumes the denominators of both parts are 1 for simplicity.

Note how sumOfRealAndImaginary is initialized to 2, and the only place it's changed is where it's incremented at the bottom of the while loop. In debug mode, when I pass getFactorization() the value 3+4i and step through the code at a sufficiently moderate speed, it returns at a time when sumOfRealAndImaginary = 3. This is what I expect. However, when I run the program, also with 3+4i as the function argument, it doesn't return until sumOfRealAndImaginary = 126, as can be seen from the WriteLine() call at the top of the while loop. In particular, the first if statement in the while loop, whose code block includes the function's return statement, takes many more passes to evaluate to true when running than when debugging. It should evaluate to true not only for the expected sumOfRealAndImaginary value of 3, but also for every value larger than that. Also, when I step through the code *sufficiently quickly* in debug mode, that if statement keeps evaluating to false until I slow down, at which point it evaluates to true on the next pass. So it would seem that whether the if statement evaluates correctly depends on how quickly the code is executed. What could cause this behavior?

There are more distinct cases of unexpected behavior I can enumerate, but perhaps this is enough to start.

Edit: The ComplexNumber class, as requested by Paweł Łukasik. Fraction is a similar class that is also derived from the Number class, which is abstract.

```
public class ComplexNumber : Number
        {
            Fraction m_real;
            Fraction m_imaginary;
            public ComplexNumber(Fraction real, Fraction imaginary)
            {
                m_real = real;
                m_imaginary = imaginary;
            }
            public ComplexNumber(int real, int imaginary)
            {
                m_real = new Fraction(real, 1);
                m_imaginary = new Fraction(imaginary, 1);
            }
            public Fraction getRealPart()
            {
                return m_real;
            }
            public Fraction getImaginaryPart()
            {
                return m_imaginary;
            }
            protected override Number add(Number number)
            {
                if (number is Fraction)
                {
                    Fraction fraction = (Fraction)number;
                    return new ComplexNumber((Fraction)(m_real + fraction), m_imaginary);
                }
                ComplexNumber complexNumber = (ComplexNumber)number;
                return new ComplexNumber((Fraction)(m_real + complexNumber.m_real),
                    (Fraction)(m_imaginary + complexNumber.m_imaginary));
            }
            protected override Number subtract(Number number)
            { 
                if (number is Fraction)
                {
                    Fraction fraction = (Fraction)number;
                    return new ComplexNumber((Fraction)(m_real - fraction), m_imaginary);
                }
                ComplexNumber complexNumber = (ComplexNumber)number;
                return new ComplexNumber((Fraction)(m_real - complexNumber.m_real),
                    (Fraction)(m_imaginary - complexNumber.m_imaginary));
            }
            protected override Number multiply(Number number)
            {
                if (number is Fraction)
                {
                    Fraction fraction = (Fraction)number;
                    return new ComplexNumber((Fraction)(m_real * fraction),
                        (Fraction)(m_imaginary * fraction));
                }
                ComplexNumber complexNumber = (ComplexNumber)number;
                return new ComplexNumber((Fraction)(m_real * complexNumber.m_real - m_imaginary *
                    complexNumber.m_imaginary), (Fraction)(m_real * complexNumber.m_imaginary +
                    m_imaginary * complexNumber.m_real));
            }
            protected override Number multiply(int scalar)
            {
                    return new ComplexNumber((Fraction)(m_real * scalar),
                        (Fraction)(m_imaginary * scalar));
            }
            protected override Number divide(Number number)
            {
                if (number is Fraction)
                {
                    Fraction fraction = (Fraction)number;
                    return new ComplexNumber((Fraction)(m_real / fraction),
                        (Fraction)(m_imaginary / fraction));
                }
                ComplexNumber complexNumber = (ComplexNumber)number;
                return new ComplexNumber((Fraction)((Fraction)(m_real * complexNumber.m_real +
                    m_imaginary * complexNumber.m_imaginary) / (Fraction)(complexNumber.m_real *
                    complexNumber.m_real + complexNumber.m_imaginary * complexNumber.m_imaginary)),
                    (Fraction)((Fraction)(m_imaginary * complexNumber.m_real -
                    m_real * complexNumber.m_imaginary) / (Fraction)(complexNumber.m_real
                    * complexNumber.m_real + complexNumber.m_imaginary * complexNumber.m_imaginary)));
            }
            public override string ToString()
            {
                StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
                if (m_imaginary.getNumerator() != 0)
                {
                    m_imaginary.reduce();
                    if (m_imaginary.getNumerator() > 0)
                    {
                        if (m_real.getNumerator() != 0)
                        {
                            output.Append(m_real.ToString());
                            output.Append("+");
                        }
                        if (m_imaginary.getNumerator() != 1)
                            output.Append(m_imaginary.getNumerator());
                    }
                    else if (m_imaginary.getNumerator() < 0)
                    {
                        if (m_real.getNumerator() != 0)
                            output.Append(m_real.ToString());
                        output.Append("-");
                        if (m_imaginary.getNumerator() != -1)
                            output.Append(-m_imaginary.getNumerator());
                    }
                    output.Append("i");
                    if (m_imaginary.getDenominator()!=1)
                    {
                        output.Append("/");
                        output.Append(m_imaginary.getDenominator());
                    }
                }
                else if (m_real.getNumerator() != 0)
                    output.Append(m_real.ToString());
                else
                    return "0";
                return output.ToString();
            }
            public override bool Equals(object obj)
            {
                if (obj is ComplexNumber)
                {
                    ComplexNumber complexNumber = (ComplexNumber)obj;
                    return m_real.Equals(complexNumber.m_real) &&
                        m_imaginary.Equals(complexNumber.m_imaginary);
                }
                return false;
            }
            public override int GetHashCode()
            {
                return m_real.GetHashCode() | m_imaginary.GetHashCode();
            }
        }
```

Edit again: [a link to a text file of the whole program](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_EYOt3EW0dYRDNqU1BrdUd5MGc), for that matter.

Comment: post your ComplexNumber class

Comment: A heisenbug suggests a race-condition, OR that your debugger is evaluating an expression that has side-effects.  Do you do *any* async, threading, background tasks, etc?

Comment: @Amy If I have any of those things, I've managed to use them without realizing it. Is there a subtle way to introduce those things into a program that doesn't involve, for example, explicitly using the async keyword or creating a Thread object? The only namespaces I use that I didn't create are System, System.Collections.Generic, and System.Text.

Comment: When you hit a breakpoint, check Visual Studio's Threads and Tasks windows.  IIRC, they're available under the Debug menu somewhere.

Comment: @Amy I opened the Threads and Tasks windows, set a breakpoint at the top of getFactorization(), and repeatedly stepped over. The Threads window always listed one thread. The Tasks window said "no tasks to display" most of the time, but if I stepped over too quickly, execution sometimes hung for a moment at the reduce() calls, and when that happened, the window went blank. Does that seem to indicate that reduce() is where to investigate further?

Comment: @Paweł Łukasik Done.

Comment: @AlexKindel great we now have the code. What expression do you type in the command line to trigger this issue. What needs to be entered so that 3+4i is passed to getFactorization?

Comment: you must be doing the debugging wrong. I'm going pretty slowly (step by step) and I'm already at this value being equal to 6.

Comment: @Paweł Łukasik (3+4i)^(1/2) will do.

Comment: @PawełŁukasik A summary what happens inside getFactorization() for me when the command line input is (3+4i)^(1/2), starting from when sumOfRealAndImaginary is incremented to 3: the next time line 755 is reached, factor is set to 1+2i. Line 760 evaluates false, so it's reset to 1-2i on line 770. Line 774 then evaluates true, so xGaussian is changed to -1+2i on line 781 and the loop is restarted. Line 742 simplifies to if(5>5), so it's still false. Line 760 again evaluates false, and 774 again evaluates true, so xGaussian is changed to -1 and the loop is restarted.

Comment: @PawełŁukasik Line 742 now simplifies to if(5>1), so getFactorization() returns, with sumOfRealAndImaginary still equal to 3.

Answer (score 0):

Someone elsewhere suggested that the problem has something to do with the fact that the overload for ToString() I defined for the Fraction class has the side effect of calling reduce(), and since the debugger uses ToString() in order to display the values of variables, the debugger might have been messing with the innards of my Fraction objects mid-execution. There are several reasons why it doesn't make sense to me that this would be the cause of the problem, not least of which is that I'd expect it to make debugging behave strangely but leave running unaffected rather than the other way around, but I heeded their suggestion and arranged for all reducing to happen in the Fraction constructor, and this did fix the problem. If anyone has a clearer explanation of how this worked, I would appreciate hearing it.